# How to get the TagNo of a Table acording to a quantity

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I Have a Table with 2 items in that 1 item has 3 quantity and other item have 2 i need to get it like for item 1-1,2,3(3quantity) and item 2-1,2(2quantity)

```
ItemName Quantity TagNo
Cap       3        1
Cap       3        2
Cap       3        3
Shirt     2        1
Shirt     2        2
```

Comment: add your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should output to be like that ? :

[image]

Then fire below SQL Command :

```
SELECT ItemName
    ,Quantity
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ItemName
        ,Quantity ORDER BY Quantity
        ) QuantitySR
    ,TagNo
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT itemname
    ,quantity
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY itemname ORDER BY itemname
        )
FROM < table_name >;
```